# Prevent VSCode from saving GIT commands in PowerShell history

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

My PowerShell history gets polluted with GIT commands from VSCode or its GitLens extension (not sure which one actually does it since GitLens moved to Source Control panel), such as `git branch --delete`.

Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really prevention but symptomatic resolution. You could delete commands that match an existing criteria using Clear-History. This will then form part of the existing history for easy and quick execution.

Perhaps,

```
Clear-History -CommandLine *git*
```

A more clear example:

```
Get-History

Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 Set-Location C:\Test\
   2 Get-Command Clear-History
   3 Get-Command Clear-History -Syntax
   4 Get-Command Clear-History -ShowCommandInfo
   5 Get-Help Get-Alias
   6 Get-Command Get-ChildItem -Syntax
   7 Get-Help Clear-History

Clear-History -CommandLine *Help*, *Syntax
Get-History

Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 Set-Location C:\Test\
   2 Get-Command Clear-History
   4 Get-Command Clear-History -ShowCommandInfo
   8 Clear-History -CommandLine *Help*, *Syntax
```